# Can I use De Morgan's law in the third step as shown below to solve this problem?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

$(p \rightarrow q) \wedge (\neg p \rightarrow q)$

$\equiv(p \rightarrow q) \wedge (\neg p \rightarrow q)$

$\equiv(\neg p \vee q) \wedge (p \vee q)$

$\equiv \neg(\neg (\neg p \vee q) \vee \neg(p \vee q))$

$\equiv \neg((p \vee \neg q) \vee (\neg p \vee \neg q))$

$\equiv \neg((p \vee \neg p) \vee (\neg q \vee \neg q))$

$\equiv \neg(T \vee \neg q)$

$\equiv F \vee q$

$\equiv q$

Comment: It appears that you used $\neg\neg(a \wedge b) = \neg\big(\neg a \vee \neg b\big)$--which was correct (you certainly reached the correct conclusion--this expression is equivalent to the value of $q$).

Comment: ...although I think a better way would have been to see the [distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Propositional_logic): $(q \vee \neg p) \wedge (q \vee p) = q \vee (\neg p \wedge p) = q$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the step is valid. I don't know if you are told to solve in a certain way, but there are better ways to solve this problem.

One would be a truth table: since there are only two variables, you can write out the result of the expression for each pair $(p,q)$, namely $(T,T), (T,F), (F,T), (F,F)$ and realize that it is equivalent to $q$. It is also not difficult to use your logic (no pun intended) to see that this expression is equivalent to $q$.

Comment: I did it with a truth table as well, but I wanted to see if I could solve it using equivalence. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

here is another way to do this.

$ (p \to q) \wedge (\neg p \to q) \equiv(q\vee\neg p)\wedge (q \vee p) \equiv q \vee (\neg p\wedge p) \equiv q\vee F \equiv q$

Comment: Not sure about your last two steps. Are you sure that $q \vee T \equiv q$. I think you mean $q \vee F \equiv q$.

Comment: @Julia, thanks. i was converting $+, \times$ to $\vee, \wedge.$ is fixed now.